# Using ‘require’ for browser-side js on module installed with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, requirejs, figma

I’m building a Figma plugin and need to make a POST request to another API, so I installed the node package ‘node-fetch’ with npm i node-fetch, and am trying to bring it into my project with: const fetch = require(‘node-fetch’);

However, I’m getting “ReferenceError: ‘require’ is not defined”. Figma plugins, by my understanding, run in a browser-like environment. How do I use require in this context? Thanks!

Comment: Webpack, Browserify, Rollup, esbuild, ...

Comment: @code - But `node-fetch()` doesn't run in the browser as it's based on the nodejs http module so there's no point in using some packing tool.  Besides, `fetch()` already exists in the browser which is what node-fetch is built to emulate.

Comment: @jfriend00 in general, at least; but yes, fetch indeed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `require()` or `node-fetch` in a browser.

`fetch()` is built-into a browser already.  Just use that.

`node-fetch` does not run in a browser.  It's built on nodejs-specific code (the nodejs http module) and its job is to emulate the implementation of `fetch()` in a browser.

So, just use the browser's own `fetch()` implementation.  Here's the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).